# JavaScript: Binding the context of object's methods to parent

Tags: javascript, object, methods, binding, this

This example works as expected:

```
class A {
  constructor(name) {
     this.name = name
  }
}

A.prototype.someMethod1 = function() { console.log("1: " + this.name) }
A.prototype.someMethod2 = function() { console.log("2: " + this.name) }

let a = new A("John")
a.someMethod1()
a.someMethod2()
```

Sometimes we need methods to be grouped by it's meaning into child objects, to call it like: a.some.method1(), a.some.method2(). Let's try to write:

```
class A {
  constructor(name) {
     this.name = name
  }
}

A.prototype.some = {
  method1: function() { console.log("1: " + this.name) },
  method2: function() { console.log("2: " + this.name) }
}
```

Now we able to call a.some.method1() and a.some.method2(), but "this" inside of it points to "a.some" and not to "a" as desired. So, "this.name" inside these metods now will be "undefined".

So can I bind context of methods to main object?

Currently I know only one method to do that. Something like this in constructor:

```
class A {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name

    // bind context to this
    Object.keys(this.name).forEach(n => {
      this.name[n] = this.name[n].bind(this)
    })
  }
}
```

But are there more elegant methods?

Note: it should be specified at the declaration time. Modifications of method calls like a.some.method1().call(a) are not acceptable.

Comment: _"Sometimes we need methods to be grouped by it's meaning into child objects"_ - What's the reasoning behind this? Aren't they all just methods of the instance? Why is this grouping needed?

Comment: for example, if I have a kind of plugins extending some class, I don't want let them to litter the object scope. I prefer a way when each plugin will put it's methods to separate scope key named by plugin's name. I think it's not the only case when this needed.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be at all what you're looking for, but you could consider doing something like this:

```
class A {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.some = new Some(this);        
    }
}

class Some {
    constructor(a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    method1() { console.log("1: " + this.a.name) }
    method2() { console.log("2: " + this.a.name) }
}

var x = new A('x name');
x.some.method1();
x.some.method2();
```

Comment: Yes, this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible you can define the instance of class and then add method on prototype by binding it to `a`

```js
class A {
  constructor(name) {
     this.name = name
  }
}

let a = new A("Hello")

A.prototype.some = {
  method1: function() { console.log("1: " + this.name) }.bind(a),
  method2: function() { console.log("2: " + this.name) }.bind(a)
}

a.some.method1()
```

Comment: no, this is not acceptable. I wrote that it must be in the declaration. Client code should not know about realisation details.

Answer (score 0):

You could make `some` a function that returns a object where you can specify what methods to have and then you can call those methods from that object.

```js
class A {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}


A.prototype.someMethod1 = function() {
  console.log("1: " + this.name)
}
A.prototype.someMethod2 = function() {
  console.log("2: " + this.name)
}

A.prototype.some = function() {
  return {
    someMethod1: this.someMethod1.bind(this),
    someMethod2: this.someMethod2.bind(this)
  }
}

let a = new A("John")
a.someMethod1()
a.someMethod2()
a.some().someMethod1()
a.some().someMethod2()
```

The same logic can be implemented with class methods without prototype. You can also omit the bind with arrow functions as class properties but you should care about support in this case.

```js
class A {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }

  some1 = () => `1. ${this.name}`
  some2 = () => `2. ${this.name}`

  some = () => {
    return {
      some1: this.some1,
      some2: this.some2
    }
  }
}

let a = new A("John")
console.log(a.some1())
console.log(a.some2())
console.log(a.some().some1())
console.log(a.some().some2())
```

You can also use getter for `some` so you can call it like property instead of method.

```js
class A {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }

  some1 = () => `1. ${this.name}`
  some2 = () => `2. ${this.name}`

  get some() {
    return {
      some1: this.some1,
      some2: this.some2
    }
  }
}

let a = new A("John")
console.log(a.some1())
console.log(a.some2())
console.log(a.some.some1())
console.log(a.some.some2())
```

Comment: In this case we do not solve the primary goal - to keep scope of main object clean.

Comment: @WindBridges You can create another class specifically for this purpose that inherits from the first class https://jsfiddle.net/s3zy47mh/1/